# Simple way to delete users account?

Tags: python, django, web

Is there a simple way or code to delete the account from a user? I want to delete the username, email address, first_name, last_name and the profile-data.

I do have two apps

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking to delete the user database record?  If so, search for it then call delete:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='their_username')
user.delete()
```

Comment: Depending on the real requirement here, it's recommended to set 'is_active' to False instead of deleting.  See:  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: Hey, I do use the registration-0.8-alpha brom Bennett. In Germany it is very stricted to delete all user information immediately, when the user wants do delete his account, so I can't set it on in_active! 
Thanks!

Comment: Then you may break things by deleting the entire user record, if you have other places in your app that refer to User records.  In other words, you'll end up with dangling User references.  After you delete the User, you should go through your schema and find those references and clean them up.

Answer (score 0):

Can You Explain What kind of application you Use? If you use some kind of database with your application then simply run delete query with some specific condition

Comment: Hey, I do use the registration-0.8-alpha brom Bennett.